# Import implicit variable for generic class from implementation

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I have an issue in Scala I'm really stuck on. I know the title is probably more confusing so let me try to explain it as easy as possible. Imagine I have an `abstract class` called `Repo`. This class describes a couple of methods on them, most of them are already implemented. The class `Repo` looks like this:

```
abstract class Repo[T](name: String) {

  implicit def collection(implicit db: DefaultDB): JSONCollection =
    db.collection[JSONCollection](name)

  def findOne(selector: JsObject)(implicit collection: JSONCollection): Future[Option[T]] = {
    collection.find(selector).one[T]
  }

  ...

}
```

A basic implementation of this class would look like this:

```
import models.Models.Resume._

object ResumeRepo extends Repo[Resume]("resumes")
```

Now if I try to compile this, it gives me an error, saying: "No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type." which is odd because I explicitly include the implicit `Format` in the `ResumeRepo` implementation class. Why is this error displaying?

Comment: Strange that the warning mentions `T` instead of the type resolved as this type parameter at compile-time.

Comment: Well.. where is the implementation of `Format` or `Writes` you say you explicitly have?

Comment: @m-z It's defined in the Resume model. The Resume model is just a case-class and the format is just based on the case-class. Do I need to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `one[T]` expects an implicit `Reads[T]` to be accessible at its application site. Which means the implicit is selected in the definition of `findOne`, in the class `Repo`, for the generic type `T`. So you need to make such an implicit visible there.

You have three options. You can add an implicit argument of type `Reads[T]`

- to findOne :

  ```
  def findOne(selector: JsObject)(implicit collection: JSONCollection, readsT : Reads[T]) : ...
  ```

  That way the implicit has to be visible when findOne is called.
- as class implicit argument:

  ```
  abstract class Repo[T](name: String)(implicit readsT : Reads[T]) { ...
  ```

That way it is visible anywhere in `Repo` but it must be visible at inheriting and instantiating site. For example you can't put the implicit in `RepoResume` because it has to be visible at object creation.

- finaly as abstract value member of the abstract class

  ```
  abstract class Repo[T](name: String) {
     implicit val readsT : Reads[T]
   ...
  }

  object RepoResume extends Repo[Resume]("resume") {
     implicit val readsT : Reads[T] = ....
  }
  ```

Comment: Could you also tell me why the `implicit def` of the collection is not working as it should. I just compiled your suggestion and this is also giving me an error now.

Comment: `could not find implicit value for parameter collection: JSONCollection`